# Why can't I see UDP on ncat after closing the initial program?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I have a short program to send UDP data to a local socket like so.

```
const char *i = "localhost";
const char *p = "8980";

struct addrinfo h;
struct addrinfo *res = 0;

memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
hints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;

if (getaddrinfo(i, p, &hints, &res) != 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: getaddinfo\n");
}

int fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
if (fd == -1)
{ 
    printf("ERROR: socket\n");
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}

if (sendto(fd, "hello", 5, 0, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR: Sending\n");
}

freeaddrinfo(res);
close(fd);
```

I have launched ncat in a different terminal window with `ncat -ul localhost 8980` and I can see "hello" on it when I subsequently launch the above program. I can also perform repeated calls to `sendto` and see hello multiple times. The program terminates but I cannot see an additional "hello" message on ncat when I relaunch the sending program. Why is this?

I've also tried not calling `close` at the end of the program as well.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you omit `localhost` from the `ncat` parameters so it listens on all local addresses? Since you are not `bind()`ing the UDP socket in your code, or even sending to every address that `getaddrinfo()` returns (it can return multiple addresses, even a mix of IPv4 and IPv6 due to your use of `AF_UNSPEC)`, it is possible that `ncat` is only listening on one interface adapter, and your first run of your apps implicitly binds to that same interface, but a subsequent run doesn't.

Comment: Also FYI, your code will crash if `getaddrinfo()` fails, since you continue to use `res` even though it won't be pointing to anything meaningful. You should exit your code immediately if `getaddrinfo()` or `socket()` fails.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that every time you run your program it will send its data from a different port, and thus be seen as a different network endpoint.  When `ncat` 
first receives a packet, it will bind to the remote endpoint and stop listening for packets coming from any other endpoint.

You can work around this with `ncat` by using the `-k` option.  Sadly, `ncat`'s `-k` option can only be used with the `-e` or `-c` options when doing UDP.  You can make it work with:

```
ncat -ulkc "cat > $(tty)" localhost 8980
```

It will still bind to each remote endpoint it gets anything from though, so there's a limit to the number of times it will work (default 100, configurable via the `-m` option).

It's a bit easier if you use `nc` instead.  It's `-k` option works normally with `-u`:

```
nc -ulk localhost 8980
```

That will prevent `nc` from binding to the remote endpoint at all, so it doesn't have the same limit as `ncat`.